# How to login to Facebook using react native for web platform

Tags: react-native, web, expo, facebook-login

I'm trying to figure out how to implement a facebook login via a react-native for a web app. I can find lots of info on how to do this for IOS and Android, but nothing for a web app. I created my project using expo and also installed firebase, but I can't find enough info to tie all this together for a web app. I don't think it will matter, but I'm also using typescript. I would provide some code, but I can't even find a solution that compiles at this point.